# Special enumerate for MCQ

Tags: enumerate

Please I want to modify the following code to get for example a red circle (fill=red!10) for the correct choice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,enumerate}

\makeatother
\def\mycirc\csname#1\endcsname{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(C.base)]
\node[draw,circle,inner sep=2pt, font=\bf](C) {\csname #1\endcsname};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

Which of the following is {\bf true}:
\begin{enumerate}[\mycirc A] 
\item 1+1=11
\item 1-1= 2
\item 1+1=1
\item 1-1+1=1
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The choice for `\bf` is definitely wrong ;-)  -- Who chooses the answer? You?

Comment: You don't need a `\makeatletter....` pair (and if you would need it, then the other way round ;-)))

Answer (score 4):

Something like a `\ifiscorrect` conditional that acts for a filled circle or a non-filled on.

Say `\iscorrecttrue` for the correct answer in front of the `\item` command.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz,enumerate}

 \newif\ifiscorrect


 \def\mycirc\csname#1\endcsname{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(C.base)]
   \ifiscorrect
   \node[fill=red,draw,circle,inner sep=2pt, font=\bfseries](C) {\csname #1\endcsname};
   \global\iscorrectfalse
   \else
   \node[draw,circle,inner sep=2pt, font=\bfseries](C) {\csname #1\endcsname};
   \fi
 \end{tikzpicture}}




 \begin{document}

 Which of the following is \textbf{true}:
 \begin{enumerate}[\mycirc A] 
 \item 1+1=11
 \item 1-1= 2
 \item  1+1=1
 \iscorrecttrue \item 1-1+1=1
 \end{enumerate}


 \end{document}
```

[image]

A `enumitem` approach would be possible too, of course.